# Reindex adding new fields in ElasticSearch doesn't work... (php client)

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have and index in elasticsearch that I want to add some new mapping/fields...

I'm using the elasticsearch php client.

My steps:

1 - Create TMP index with the new mapping/fields - **OK**

2 - Reindex from OLD index to the TMP index - **OK** (te new index have the new fields)

3 - Reindex form TMP index to the OLD one - **KO** (I lose the new mapping/fields and I don't know why)

4 - Delete the TMP index - **OK**

5 - Here I have the OLD index (good) with the OLD mapping (bad)

How can I have the new mapping/fields in the original index?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

In your 3rd step you don't loose the new mapping, you just don't have it from beggining and reindexing don't copy the mapping you need to update the mapping on OLD index before reindexing.

1. Create TMP w/mapping
2. Reindex OLD ---> TMP
3. Delete OLD and create OLD w/mapping
4. Delete TMP
5. Here you'll have OLD index with new mapping

ALL GOOD!!!

If you check the documentation about reindex
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.2/docs-reindex.html

There's important warning :

> Reindex does not attempt to set up the destination index. It does not
>   copy the settings of the source index. **You should** set up the
>   destination index **prior to running a _reindex action**, including
>   **setting up mappings**, shard counts, replicas, etc.

Other solution is using Alias.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.2/indices-aliases.html